# How can I make a program wait for the user to type in a textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms

When I run a Windows Forms program to a line, I would like to check if a textbox already has user input. If not, I will ask the user to type in the textbox and wait till the user types in some input, before running the next line of the code. How can I do the wait?

The program has to wait for the information required as input for the next line of code.

Comment: There is no need of fancy timer and checking if the textbox content changed. I would simply subscribe to the `TextChanged` event of the textbox and react when that event is triggered.

Comment: That's not how a GUI works. If you wait, the UI will hang and the user cannot enter anything. You could however react on the [TextChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged) event and proceed to the next processing step from there

Comment: don't wait, Use `event` like `Control.TextChanged Event` to execute some code when the conditions are met.

Comment: @Cleptus The program has to wait for the information required as input for the next line of code.

Comment: @KlausGütter ditto

Comment: @JonathanApplebaum ditto

Comment: @Tim: This is why nearly all GUIs operate as : fill in all input boxes first, then press a button.  The work is done when the button is pressed.  There's no "next line of code" that needs to wait before the textbox was filled in, because the code doesn't even run until the user fills everything and presses the button.

Comment: Once you have the basic "run the processing in button click event", you can worry about handling other events, e.g. to turn an input red immediately when its value is out of range, or hide/show some input boxes depending on a checkbox.  But don't worry about fancy user interactions until you have the basic "fill in the form, press the button, do the work" flow going.

Comment: @KlausGütter the UI will only hang if you wait on the same thread as the UI

Comment: You need to understand the concept of 'event-driven' applications, which is the default.

Answer (score 2):

Waiting for something to happen in the GUI (using a timer, loops from other threads, etc...) is a massive waste of resources.
 Almost all functional programming languages have [Events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming) including `C#`

From Wikipedia:

> event-driven programming is a programming paradigm in which the flow
> of the program is determined by events such as user actions (mouse
> clicks, key presses), sensor outputs, or message passing from other
> programs or threads. Event-driven programming is the dominant paradigm
> used in graphical user interfaces and other applications (e.g.,
> JavaScript web applications) that are centered on performing certain
> actions in response to user input. This is also true of programming
> for device drivers (e.g., P in USB device driver stacks).

You can do it like this with the help of `Control.TextChanged` event inherited by the `Textbox` control:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ValidateGUI();
}

private const int MIN_CHARS_TO_DO_SOMETHING = 8;
private const string NOT_VALID = "Oh No There is No User Input )-:";
private const string VALID = "Great We Can Do Something (-:";

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ValidateGUI();
}

private void ValidateGUI()
{
    if (textBox1.Text.Length < MIN_CHARS_TO_DO_SOMETHING)
    {
        lblMessege.Text = NOT_VALID;
    }
    else
    {
        lblMessege.Text = VALID;
        // Execute some code..
        //...
        //...                  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you have a valid reason for waiting instead of monitoring input.

You just need to use background workers and then you need to set the DoWork event to wait for a specified amount of time, and the RunWorkerCompleted event to run your code checking if input is being made.

Here's an example assuming a label and a textbox are on the form already. Alternatively you can just add the background worker as a form element instead of creating it in code:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        waitForInput();
    }
    
    private void waitForInput()
    {
        BackgroundWorker waiter = new BackgroundWorker();
        waiter.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        waiter.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        waiter.DoWork += wait10Seconds;
        waiter.RunWorkerCompleted += doneWaiting;
        waiter.RunWorkerAsync();
        
    }

    private void wait10Seconds(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
    }
    private void doneWaiting(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(textBox1.Text == "")
        {
            label1.Text = "Why haven't you typed anything?";
        }
    }
```

Comment: A BackgroundWorker? For this? In case this is needed (and, based on the OP,  it's not), you can use a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` and set its `Interval` to `10000`.

Comment: @Jimi yes that would probably make more sense

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're getting at, a synchronization object like `SemaphoreSlim` might be a good fit for something like this. This declaration sets the initial count to 0 so the semaphore will block. The `initSync` method pauses halfway through and will `await` the textbox `Enter` key to release the `semaphoreSlim` before executing the next line. However, the UI thread is *not* blocked during the waiting period.

```
SemaphoreSlim _waitForText = new SemaphoreSlim(0, maxCount: 1);
private async Task initAsync()
{
    richTextBox1.AppendText(
            $"The async method that populates this RichTextBox waits indefinitely for input.");
    richTextBox1.AppendText($"{Environment.NewLine}>");;
    richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;

    // "check if a textbox already has user input"
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text))
    {
        // "ask user to type"
        textBox1.Text = "Enter ID";
        await _waitForText.WaitAsync();
    }
    else onUserInputOK();

    // The MOCK login has completed. Enable the app.
    richTextBox1.Enabled = true;

    richTextBox1.AppendText(
        $"{Environment.NewLine}Now this method will complete, and you'll see a message box in 5 seconds");
}
```

[image: await a MOCK login]

---

**Example**

```
public MainForm() => InitializeComponent();
protected override async void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    // Disable UI response until "logged in"
    richTextBox1.Enabled = false;
    // Subscribe to TextChanged event
    textBox1.KeyDown += detectUserInput;
    await initAsync();
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    MessageBox.Show("All done");
}
private void detectUserInput(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyData == Keys.Return)
    {
        e.Handled = e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text))
        {
            onUserInputOK();
        }
    }
}
private void onUserInputOK()
{
    richTextBox1.AppendText($"{textBox1.Text}");
    Text = textBox1.Text; // Start echo to title bar
    richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.DarkGreen;
    // Remove this listener. Install normal runtime hook.
    textBox1.KeyDown -= detectUserInput;
    textBox1.TextChanged += normalTextboxListener;
    _waitForText.Release();
}
private void normalTextboxListener(object sender, EventArgs e) => Text = textBox1.Text;
```